# File loader does not work as expected in webpack2

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack-2

I am trying to load 3 js files from shared folder to respected output folder and its working fine for images but not for js.
In my index.html page I have use 3 js files such as

```
<script src="../src/app/shared/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../src/app/shared/assets/js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="../src/app/shared/assets/js/SigWebTablet.js"></script>
```

after taking build the scripts are no longer accessed because the folder `src/app/shared` does not exist after build.
My webpack.config is somewhat like

```
{
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/js/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                ]
            }
```

And my build folder structure looks like

```
dist
    --assets
       --log.png
    --app.js
    --vendor.js
    --polyfills.js
    --index.html
```

And I expected to load the 3 js files into the assets folder like

```
 dist
        --assets
           --js
              --jquery.min.js
              --html2canvas.min.js
              --sigWebTablet.js
           --log.png
        --app.js
        --vendor.js
        --polyfills.js
        --index.html
```

Could anyone please suggest a better solution.

Comment: Not sure whether it will be possible , it seems app/vendor.js will bundle all the files

Comment: @bkr But this script does not have .d.ts file and if I add the script in vendor.ts file using require(../SigWebTablet.js) it bundles the script but not referenced in the component